# src="" not returning when saving images?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in my net.core project. While saving the datatable, the image I added does not appear, it is registered to the database as

```
<figure class="image"><img></figure>
```

and src= does not appear as in lowermost the image. My adapter function is as follows

```
class MyUploadAdapter
{
 constructor(loader) {
 // The file loader instance to use during the upload.
      this.loader = loader;
      this.urls = '/tr/UnitType/DocUploadImage';
         }
        // Starts the upload process.
         upload() {
     return this.loader.file.then(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         this._initRequest();
         this._initListeners(resolve, reject, file);
         this._sendRequest(file);
                }));
            }
 // Aborts the upload process.
    abort() {
    if (this.xhr) {
    this.xhr.abort();
    }
    }

    _initRequest() {
    const xhr = this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', this.urls, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    }
  // Initializes XMLHttpRequest listeners.
    _initListeners(resolve, reject, file) {
     const xhr = this.xhr;
     const loader = this.loader;
     const genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${file.name}.`;

     xhr.addEventListener('error', () => reject(genericErrorText));
     xhr.addEventListener('abort', () => reject());
     xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
     const response = xhr.response;

   if (!response || response.error) {
     return reject(response && response.error ? response.error.message : genericErrorText);
     }
    resolve({
         default: response.urls
              });
               });

        if (xhr.upload) {
           xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', evt => {
           if (evt.lengthComputable) {
           loader.uploadTotal = evt.total;
           loader.uploaded = evt.loaded;
        }
        });
                }
            }

            // Prepares the data and sends the request.
            _sendRequest(file) {
                // Prepare the form data.
                const data = new FormData();

                data.append('upload', file);

                this.xhr.send(data);
            }
        }

        function MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin(editor) {
            editor.plugins.get('FileRepository').createUploadAdapter = (loader) => {
                return new MyUploadAdapter(loader);
            };
        }
```

I want to export this.urly to src. How is it given correctly? Is it possible in this way, if not how should I do it please help

```
                DecoupledEditor
                    .create(document.querySelector('#p_Ack')
                       ,{
                           extraPlugins: [MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin],
                           elements:
                           {
                               img: function (element) {
                                   const img = document.querySelector("img");
                                   img.src = this.url;
                                   
                           }
                               }
                        }
                    )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAuPH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbwdG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem..
For friends who have the same problem, @KIM-DONGWON answered the solution on https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/5709.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).